# Wix conditional component installation based on checking if fileSearch property is unset

Tags: visual-c++, wix, windows-installer

As per requirement of our product install, we need to install some dlls in C:\Windows\System32 in user's computer. Since Windows Installer automatically installs the higher version if source has a version higher than destination and in doing so modifies the user's system without user's knowledge, I want the component block to not fire at all when the dll is already present in C:\Windows\System32. That's why I'm doing a FileSearch and setting a property to a value in case the file exists. According to documents, it will be the path of the file specified.

```
    <Property Id="VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL">
      <DirectorySearch Id="vcomp_parent_dir" Path="$(var.SystemPlatformFolder)">
        <FileSearch Id="vcomp_file" Name="vcomp140.dll"/>
      </DirectorySearch>
    </Property>
```

Later on I'm using the VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL property, as in the following block to install the component conditionally.

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="AdditionalDependencies" Directory="$(var.SystemPlatformFolder)">
        <?if $(var.vcomp140_exists) = "true"?>
            <Component>
              <Condition>NOT VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL</Condition>
              <File Source="$(var.AdditionalDependenciesRoot)/OpenMP/vcomp140.dll"/>
            </Component>
        <?endif?>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

Issue is that when I tested it for the case when the file is present in destination, I see that my installer file, which is higher version, has replaced the file in destination, whereas according to above logic, it shouldn't have touched it. Also I don't see the property value echoed out in the verbose log. All I see in the log is this

AppSearch: Property: VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL, Signature: vcomp_file

and not something like following which is usually the case.

Property(S): VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL = C:\Windows\System32

The outer conditional pre-processor directives are to check for another condition, where var.vcomp140_exists is passed to candle.exe during compile (with the -d switch). So this is a build/compile time condition. I know that outer condition works (value passed is true). Looks like the inner install time condition block is being ignored by WI. Can you mix it up like this?

In case you can, I guess my issue is not knowing how to check for whether property value is set or not. I found somewhere in Wix document that, If search fails, property will remain undefined or it will keep its original value. In this case, I guess it will be undefined. Question is if 'NOT PROPERTYNAME' is how you check it? Any help will be much appreciated. Stuck on this issue for days!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using as a conditional is a [preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html), its resolved at build time, not runtime. You need to craft a [conditional](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation/) with an appropriate [expression](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/) that is evaluated after the file search.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an example I can look at?

Comment: I think my issue is  the properties not getting the value when the inner condition is being evaluated. I see the only way to set a property is using a setProperty. 
When I use following.

<SetProperty Id="VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL" Sequence="execute" Before="InstallFiles" Value="no">NOT VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL</SetProperty>

I see the file not getting copied even when its not present in the destination.

Log shows VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL value of what's set by setProperty.

Comment: Actually it turned out that the syntax of the inner or install time condition is right. The issue was passing the entire directory as path in the directorySearch element. When I nested the subfolders with multiple directorySearch elements (one folder per element), I was able to see the property VCOMP_EXISTS_LOCAL getting evaluated. Also it proves that you can install a component by checking build time (with the pre-processors) and install time conditions at the same time in a single component block.

Comment: And no setting of a default value for the property using setProperty (when file doesn't exist in the destination folder) is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Quite apart from the component condition situation, there is no need to do this. The standard way to distribute the VC++ redistributables is to run the redist package as a prerequisite. When you say "my installer file, which is higher version, has replaced the file in destination" then you shouldn't be doing it at all. You risk breaking the client system.

I also note that a shared Dll like that is shared using a Windows Installer component id, so that every product that uses something like vcomp140.dll will install it with the same component id. Again, you risk breaking the sharing for that Dll by just installing it with your own component id.

The correct action is to run the redist as a prerequisite and it will just do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with not mucking with the system folder. Right now we are just adding the dlls in our bin folder for simplicity.